# TOPdesk API error 401, I inserted the API key but doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, authentication

I am trying to connect to TOPdesk's API but I keep getting error 401, so it's about authentication. I have an API key though and my account is authorized to see the API data. When I try to see the data on Postman it works, but I am unable to retrieve it from the API and store in on my own database. This is a snippet of my code, with a few alterations due to privacy reasons, and also to keep it shorter:

```
...
dotenv.config();
...
// Function to fetch data from the API and store it in the database
const fetchDataFromAPI = async () => {
    const apiUrl = 'https://mycompany.topdesk.net/tas/api/....';

    try {
        // Make HTTP request to the API
        const response = await axios.get(apiUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}` //API Key is stored on a .env file.
        }
    });

        // Extract relevant data from the API response
        const incidents = response.data.incidents;

        // Insert data into the SQLite database
        incidents.forEach(async (incident) => {
            const { id, status, closedDate } = incident;

            const insertQuery = `
                INSERT INTO ticketsIT (id, status, closedDate)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
            `;

            // Execute the insert query
            db.run(insertQuery, [id, status, closedDate], (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error inserting data into the database:', err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Data inserted into the database successfully.');
                }
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data from the API:', error.message);
    }
};

// Schedule the data fetch to happen when the server starts
fetchDataFromAPI();
```

I get an error on the terminal saying Request failed with status code 401.

I tried using the API key PLAIN on the code (lmao) but now it's inside a different file. Not sure about what to do, my link works on Postman as I said but not on my code.

Answer (score 0):

what happened is that on Postman I was using Basic Auth and on my code I was using Bearer Token (oof). Problem solved now, I've changed my code so I can use Basic Auth now ;)